# What is the difference between the CCA weights and rotations?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have been looking at the scikit learn Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA) algorithm, and I have come across the terms "weights" and "rotations" as parameters of the CCA model. What is the difference between the CCA weights and rotations, and how are they related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

From the scikit-learn documentation for [Canonical Correlation Analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html) (CCA):

> x_weights_ … The left singular vectors of the cross-covariance matrices of each iteration.

> x_rotations_ … The projection matrix used to transform X.

There are similar attributes for y.